# atom.io auto create html basic structure

Tags: atom-editor

Im using atom.io for some time now and really like it. there is just one thing im missing. I used to use brackets and sublime before and they both had a feature where you could create the basic structure of a html documents by just typing html.

this would just set the html, head and body tag. created the charset meta, title and link to css file.

I create a lot of html files a day so it would be really helpfull if I know the shortcode or the package which supports this!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You're looking for [`autocomplete-snippets`](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-snippets).

Simply type `html` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Here's a terrible GIF to prove it:

[image]

Comment: wierd. thats not working for me. Ill try to reinstall!

Comment: Package works, disabled, restarted, enabled. Plus you need to save the file as HTML or alike, only then `html` will trigger. It will not work in a blank document.

Comment: I have disabled atom's autocomplete-snippets : that program is almost as annoying as that gif  :-) . I put alternate answer using a package dedicated to document templates. This lets you have multiple templates for different projects too (e.g., vanilla html, django, etc), and more directly gets at the issue imho.

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.

Comment: as simple as this is, I use it infrequently and often forget it's `html + enter` and when I hit `tab` I end up with `<html></html>` doh!  proof that shortcuts only stick if you use them often.

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice Plugin, called emmet: https://atom.io/packages/emmet

When you got that, you just have to type `! -> tab` in an empty document. You get pretty much the same result as @hatchet GIF.

Comment: recommended especially if you write a lot of html, and is a mere 2 keystrokes!

Comment: It's doesn't really produce the same code as Hatchet's answer but it works

Comment: Only difference for me is an extra `lang="en"` attribute

Comment: It works only if a file you're typing in is saved with *.html extension. In unsaved files with no extension it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you have disabled the autocomplete functionality mentioned in the currently accepted answer, or want more flexibility than that allows, there is a `file-templates` package:
https://atom.io/packages/file-templates

Here are some basic instructions.

- To install the package: `edit->preferences->install->file-templates`.
- To save the template: `packages->new template from this file`.
- To open a new file with that template, just hit `ctrl-alt-n` and
  select it.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure your file has .html added on the end of its name.**

Then go back into Atom, type HTML, and press enter. Your boilerplate should appear. Solved my problem instantly!

Answer (score 0):

If we install Emmet package we are not getting the boiler plate code. So I disabled emmet and it is working fine for me.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this answer? Give more details and explain how it helps answer the question

Answer (score 0):

!tab is the command u seek. But it won't work unless you create a file and save it with the html extension...

So go create a new file in the directory u want, call it index.html and now go type !tab

It should work 100%, if not be sure u have emmet installed.